# Pulling a specific value from a Pandas GroupBy Object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, typeerror

Running Python 3.6.4, pandas 0.22 and numpy 1.14.1

I am looking to pull a specific value from a Pandas `GroupBy object`.

I am taking my initial dataset, opening into a `dataframe` filtering out unnecessary columns. Then I am doing a `groupby`, where Columns D, E, F, G and H are each summed based on columns A, B and C. This gives me the data-set that I need to pull values from.

First here's an example of the type of group by I am using. (Maybe this can be corrected)

```
output = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'], as_index=False).agg({'D': [np.sum], 'E': [np.sum],'F': [np.sum],'G': [np.sum],'H': [np.sum]})
```

If it helps, Columns A, B and C are all strings, where D through H are all converted to numbers using the `to_numeric` method.

Next, I am looking to pull a specific value out of this new data-set using the maximum value of Column A.

I can pull a series using loc, but I want to pull the value of a certain position and then insert that into another dataframe. Maybe loc does this, I just want to be certain that whatever I pull from this group by object, gets put into the new `dataframe`. So is the value is 4, I get a variable = 4, and then can put that into another `dataframe`.

```
value = output.at[output.A.idxmax(), 'D']
```

The error I am getting is `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

My best guess is that this is based on the fact that `groupby` returns a `groupby object`? Or should this work with a `groupby` object as well?

What are my options here? Maybe my `groupby` is wrong? Maybe I don't need a `groupby`? Maybe I can convert my `groupby` object to a `dataframe` and then run the `df.at`? Any help is appreciated.

Also - if I've done something wrong, please help me understand the 'why?' along with the fixed scripting. I am very interested in learning as much as I can vs. having everyone do my work for me. I love python and the capabilities, but am very much a novice at this point.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 3], 'B': ['Jon', 'Jon', 'Jane'], 'C': ['Jim', 'Jim', 'Jim'], 'D': [10,20,30], 'E': [24, 45, 56]})`

`summed = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C']).sum().reset_index()`

`max_a = summed[summed.A == summed.A.max()]`

`DataFrame.rest_index` might be of use to you. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html If you have more columns than A through H, just make sure to only select those columns before doing the groupby, sum, and reset_index. Good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate this me answer. I think your groupby statement also really helps me shorten mine. Cheers!